# 'SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;' failed after I execute it

Tags: mysql

I have a InnoDB MySQL table.
At the beginning, the `autocommit` is `ON`.

And I tried to run this:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name='autocommit';
```

Then execute it. 
Yeah, it really shows `autocommit` is `OFF` after I execute this command


But when I try to run this again:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name='autocommit';
```

The `autocommit` return to `ON` again.
Why?
Is there any way to set `autocommit` to `OFF` forever?

Comment: What are you actually using to run these queries?  The MySQL CLI?  A GUI?  A programming language/connector?

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't, autocommit is per session(another name for a "connection").

You can explicitly disable autocommit once per connection you make to the database, the setting applies to only that connection.